# What is the difference between super.doView(...) and include(...) on doView override?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am developing a custom portlet (EDIT:I'm extending MVCPortlet), and looking at several examples and tutorials, I find that when the doView(RenderRequest, RenderResponse) method is overridden, at the end of it there is always at least this line:

```
super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
```

or this:

```
include(viewJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);
```

If I don't put either of these my portlet doesn't render anything, but any of them does the trick.

I would like to know which one I should be using, and why do I need to add them to get my portlet to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you must be extending [`MVCPortlet`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/liferay/portal/util-bridges/6.1.0/util-bridges-6.1.0-sources.jar!/com/liferay/util/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.java?format=ok) class. Both the calls are used to **include** the JSP after the `doView` processing is completed. If you look at the source code of this class then you would understand what the flow is, below is my explanation:

> super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);

This includes the default JSP i.e. `view.jsp`, that you might (or not) have configured in `portlet.xml` something like this:

```
<init-param>
    <name>view-template</name>
    <value>/html/view.jsp</value>
</init-param>
```

This super class method does nothing but calls the `include(viewJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);` method at the end.

> include(viewJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);

This method includes whatever JSP path you have specified for the parameter `viewJSP`. So with this call you can specify including different JSP for different condition something like the following:

```
if (isThisTrue) {
    include("/html/myCustomPortlet/view.jsp", renderRequest, renderResponse);
} else if (isThisTrueThen) {
    include("/html/myCustomPortlet/first/another_view.jsp", renderRequest, renderResponse);
} else {
    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

So depending on your requirement you can use any to the two or the mix of the two as shown above. Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, I am extending MVCPortlet. I am affraid I forgot to clarify that. I have followed your suggestion, and downloaded the source code. I see that, as you say, both options do the same thing! because super.doView(...) calls include(...) itself using 'viewTemplate' (which is the default view.jsp). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The include lets you specify a different JSP to use instead of the default view.  So if you are not using a custom view page either will work.